# Java Multi Threading not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing the following code to read entries from file and check whether they are palindromes or not in a multithreaded environment. But somehow the code is working till a specific limit. I really can't figure out why it is not reading all the values from the ArrayList. Any help will be appreciated!

Palindromeworker.java

```
package Palindrome;

import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by aliabbasjaffri on 05/10/15.
 */
public class PalindromeWorker implements Runnable
{
    int key;
    static int ID = 0;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public PalindromeWorker( int keyWord )
    {
        ID++;
        key = keyWord + 1;
        words = DataClass.mapBagOfTasks.get(key);
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome(String str)
    {
        return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello From Thread: " + ID);

        if(words != null)
        {
            for (String word : words)
            {
                if (isPalindrome(word))
                {
                    if (DataClass.Palindromes.containsKey(key))
                        DataClass.Palindromes.get(key).add(word);

                    else
                    {
                        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                        arr.add(word);
                        DataClass.Palindromes.put(key, arr);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Done from Thread: " + ID);
        }


    }
}
```

PalindromeWriter.java

```
package Palindrome;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by aliabbasjaffri on 05/10/15.
 */
public class PalindromeWriter implements Runnable
{
    int key;
    static int ID = 0;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public PalindromeWriter( int keyWord )
    {
        ID++;
        key = keyWord + 1;
        words = DataClass.Palindromes.get( key );
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello From Output Thread: " + ID);

        try
        {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( DataClass.outputFileName , true)));

            if(words != null)
            {
                for (String word : words)
                {
                    out.println( word );
                }
            }

            out.println("Done from Thread: " + ID);

            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
package Main;

import Palindrome.*;

/**
 * Created by aliabbasjaffri on 05/10/15.
 */
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Palindrome obj = new Palindrome();

        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new PalindromeWorker( i ));
                t.start();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                new Thread(new PalindromeWriter(i)).start();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
Done from Thread: 1
ii
Done from Thread: 2
AAA
ABA
ala
AMA
ana
bib
bob
bub
CDC
dad
did
DOD
dud
eke
ere
eve
ewe
eye
gag
gig
gog
huh
iii
mum
non
nun
pap
PDP
pep
pip
pop
pup
sis
s's
tat
tit
TNT
tot
wow
Done from Thread: 3
deed
noon
peep
poop
teet
toot
Done from Thread: 4
civic
level
madam
minim
radar
refer
rever
rotor
tenet
Done from Thread: 5
Done from Thread: 6
Done from Thread: 7
Done from Thread: 8
Done from Thread: 9
Done from Thread: 10
Done from Thread: 11
Done from Thread: 12
Done from Thread: 13
Done from Thread: 14
Done from Thread: 15
Done from Thread: 16
Done from Thread: 17
Done from Thread: 18
Done from Thread: 19
Done from Thread: 20
Done from Thread: 21
Done from Thread: 22
```

Comment: You define the ID in your `Runnable` as `static` which means the variable is shared through all instances. This will for sure give you the impression of a wrong output. Easiest way to fix this is you pass an ID into the constructor.

Comment: Well, that doesn't really adds much of difference here. Even if i do pass it as a parameter, it will give the same output. I really need to know where am i going wrong. The ArrayList palindrome contains many more entries when i debugged it, not just the result set that is shown above.

Comment: You also haven't locked down your `get(key)` on Palindromes.

Comment: What would be the point in doing that? @jnbbender

Comment: A few things : 1) You do not wait your readers to have finished before launching the writers. 2) your IDs being static may work (courtesy of Thread.sleep), but why risk it ? 3) you do not wait your writer threads to stop 4) you have simultaneous writes in your DataClass.Palindromes "map" (even if on different keys, it may not be safe) 5) your writers write concurrently to your "Printer". Could you expand on that ?